# Passing data into an Adobe Air App continuously

Tags: javascript, flash, service, air

I have an HTML/JavaScript Adobe AIR app which needs to be listening for data coming in from an external process.

I could have the AIR app itself invoked by the external process. If anyone knows how this could be done in such a way that AIR would then continue to listen for messages/events from the process which invoked it, then I would like to hear about it.

Failing that, can I set up some kind of endpoint in AIR itself to accept data through?

I've experimented with a Native Process, and while having AIR launch the process allows it to read data in, the native process itself to be externally accessible, plus it must be able to write to STDOUT for Adobe AIR to receive. I can't do this with a service.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the answer to a similar question, I was able to do this by building a service host onto a .NET console app which I start from Adobe AIR's NativeProcess command. Data is passed on STDOUT from the console of the service, and picked up via the STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA event in AIR.

Works well, and the communication is quick.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into using HTTP socket connections from within Flash.

**as3httpclientlib** might be a good place to start:

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=http+socket+as3&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8